# PlasticSCM, Citrix Set up: How to force plasticscm to request login to plastic server everytime

Tags: citrix, plasticscm

I am setting up plasticscm into our citrix environment. I am facing issue where the plasticscm client is using credentials from a previous citrix session, which may be from a different user.

I see the followng options available, list in order of preference:

1. plasticscm would support sso and would log into the plastic scm server 
    with the credentials entered into citrix.
2. plasticscm client would request credentials after each citrix login
3. plasticscm client would request credentials every time client is launched.

How would the plasticscm be configured to support any of these options?

thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

We have a workaround that some of our costumers are using in a similar scenario.

You need to copy the "client.conf.template" file in the Plastic client folder and run the Plastic GUI using the "plastic.bat" script.

This scripts replaces the existing "client.conf" file by a new "client.conf" file. This way you will need to enter the password each time you open the Plastic GUI.

You can download the files here:
[scripts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zlka91Yw6xh3hqNG05LQeiLk1x8cuMlt/view?usp=sharing)

Don´t hesitate to reach us at support@codicesoftware if you have more questions.

Comment: Anyway, if I'm not mistaken, if the creds are reused, it could mean the client.conf is setup at a global level (together with the client binaries) instead of locally for the user, which is the default. Can that be the case?